# Facebook PHP separate array

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am trying to get the name of the person who has posted the post, but I don't understand how to get the name from the array.

Here is the full code:
http://pastebin.com/88ADm5Uw

This is the line I have a problem with:

```
echo "FROM: " . print_r($post['from']) . '<br>';
```

This line returns two values(id and name) and I want to only print out the name. Please help!:

EDIT:
Any way to get the profile picture?

Comment: What's `$post`? Where is it initialized? Can you get the information directly from `$_POST['from']?

Comment: What post? What person? What array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
echo "FROM: " . print_r($post['from']['name']) . '<br>';
```

You can see the complete JSON here:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%2Fhome

Comment: Thanks for the answer! btw, do you know how i can get the date when the post was created, posted(the method in my code shows todays date)?

Comment: `$post['created_time']` or `$post['updated_time']`. Did you click on the link I've mentioned in the answer? That has the complete json response.

Answer (score 1):

`$post['from']` is an array containing name and id.  If you only want to print out the name, you could do something like `echo $post['from']['name']` I believe.